# Как убрать content для ::after с помощью :last-child?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Я с помощью псевдоэлемента ::after для параграфов с классом .nav_butt добавил content: " |", что должно разделять параграфы между собой. Все хорошо, но в последнем параграфе появляется ненужный мне "|", которого, хотелось бы заметить нет у первого элемента. Первая мысль пришедшая в голову: использовать :last-child. Но представления не имею, как это все должно выглядеть. Код и картинка ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

html:

```
<nav class="nav_hat">
    <p class="nav_butt white_text">HOME</p>
    <p class="nav_butt white_text">SALE</p>
    <p class="nav_butt white_text">HANDBAGS</p>
    <p class="nav_butt white_text">WALLETS</p>
    <p class="nav_butt white_text">ACCESSORIES</p>
    <p class="nav_butt white_text">MENS STORE</p>
    <p class="nav_butt white_text">SHOES</p>
    <p class="nav_butt white_text">VINTAGE</p>
    <p class="nav_butt white_text">SERVICES</p>
    <p class="nav_butt white_text">CONTACT US</p>
</nav>
```

css:

```
.nav_hat {
background: #4ccfc1;
}

.nav_butt {
    margin: 10px 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.nav_butt::after {
    content: ' |'
}

.nav_butt:last-child {

}
```

Comment: `.nav_butt:last-child:after{content: "";}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо

```
nav_butt::after {
    content: ' |';
}
```

Надо

```
.nav_butt:not(:last-child)::after {
    content: ' |';
}
```

или

```
.nav_butt + .nav_butt::before {
    content: '|';
    padding: 0 4px;
}
```